# Can I specify where my database files are stored *per database* in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to have two databases hosted on a single MySQL instance, but have the files stored in two different physical locations?

For example:

db1 stored in: `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/`

db2 stored in: `E:/MySQL/MoreData/`

I know there's a `datadir` setting in `my.ini` that specifies where to store databases by default.  Is there any way to override this at the database level?

I suppose I could use shortcuts, but is there a built-in way to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use symbolic links, or in your case, the [MySQL workaround for Windows, the .sym file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-symbolic-links.html).