# Can I tell MySQL to store specific databases in specific folders?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have 2 databases, "foo" and "bar", 
and I want MySQL to store "foo" in "/media/foo", and "bar" in "/media/bar", 
can this be done in MySQL 5.5 or later?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/158218/can-i-specify-where-my-database-files-are-stored-per-database-in-mysql

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally each database is already in a subdirectory of its own. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-database.html) :

> A database in MySQL is implemented as a directory containing files that correspond to tables in the database. Because there are no tables in a database when it is initially created, the `CREATE DATABASE` statement creates only a directory under the MySQL data directory and the db.opt file.
>   ...
>   If you manually create a directory under the data directory (for example, with `mkdir`), the server considers it a database directory and it shows up in the output of `SHOW DATABASES`.

With [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html) with the  `DATA DIRECTORY = absolute_path_to_directory` clause of the CREATE TABLE statement you can even create tables outside of the normal MySQL (sub-) directory structures